# Can we provide conditionally 'bindValue' in ng-select?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

```
<ng-select
[items]="selectdata"
bindLabel="name"
bindValue="bindValue?bindValue:''"
[multiple]="selectMultiple"
[placeholder]="placeholder"
[(ngModel)]="inputModel"
[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
[formControl]="formGroup"
[clearable]="clearable"
[searchable]="searchable"
```

> 

This is the child component.

```
<app-csselect
      #csselectcomponent
      [inputDesign]="'ngselect'"
      [selectdata]="selectdata"
      [inputLabel]="'This is label'"
      [(inputModel)]="selectbox"
      [selectMultiple]="true"
      [searchable]="true"
      formControlName="selectbox"
    ></app-csselect>
```

this is parent component,
where I am trying to access the child object. now I want to bind the value because I have requirement that, I can select when I want to return 'id' or whole 'object'.
here, I have tried with dynamic binding of property of bindValue, but if empty string comes up, then the value I get is 'undefined'.

- if we don't take **bindValue** then, we can access whole object and when we apply bindValue = id then we can fetch id, is there anyway we can do that?

Comment: You should check this 3rd party package APIs. This is a common scenario and should be handled in the package. Provide code on stackblitz to check in details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional `bindValues` like this:

```
<ng-select
[items]="selectdata"
bindLabel="name"
[bindValue]="bindValue ? bindValue :''"
[multiple]="selectMultiple"
[placeholder]="placeholder"
[(ngModel)]="inputModel"
[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
[formControl]="formGroup"
[clearable]="clearable"
[searchable]="searchable"
```